# Mvc: Linq OrderBy custom parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

I have the next linq query

```
public IEnumerable<Table> GetTablePage(int pageNumber, int pageSize, string searchCriteria)
{
    Entities db = new Entities();

    if (pageNumber < 1)
    {
        pageNumber = 1;
    }

    return entities.Table.OrderBy(searchCriteria).Skip((pageNumber - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
}
```

It´s working fine, but i have some table fields where i need to do some joins for retrieving information, it's because in my Table i only have the code and i really need the name.
**Example** -> customerId is foreign key in Table, and i would like to get the customerName, but actually i can´t because `entities.Table` only has customerId, What´s the best way to return the information without losing  `Table.OrderBy(searchCriteria)... properties`  ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that you are using Dynamic Linq to pass a string to your orderBy. 
How do you filter your result with an OrderBy? i suppose that you try to filter using your searchCriteria?

Now some kind of answer might be....

If you include the child table in your query, then the child will be a part of your Table object.

```
entities.Table.Include("Customer").OrderBy(....
```